# Scale font-size to parent for the css content attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I am using font awesome for a very long time. But few days back i came across a situation where in i needed to set the font size automatically so that the content covers the entire space of the parent element.

I know about some libraries and methods to do it with text fit and similar but the problem is that they work for the text inside an element. However font awesome works with the css content property and we are required to se the size of the font manually. Is there any way so that i can set the font size to scale to parent element.

Example of css:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid;
}

i {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <i class="far fa-user-circle" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, who is setting the `CSS` above? Because if you are setting it. just add `font-size: 300px` into the `div` CSS and remove the `i` statement.

Comment: @Bibberty That will set each line to 300px, which I don't think is what the OP wants.

Comment: Did you see this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: @Whatatimetobealive i have seen and that not fixing in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some script to do the job

```js
const getComputedStyle = (element, style) => {
  let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);  
  return computedStyle[style];
};

let container = document.querySelector('div');
let icon = document.querySelector('div i');
let h = getComputedStyle(container, 'height');
icon.style.fontSize = `${h}`;
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid;
}

i {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <i class="far fa-user-circle" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note: You need to use the computed style function I have included.